TS doesn't infer type has a property after conditional check
I have this TS code:
type MyFunctions = {
  play(): void
  pause(args: { reset: boolean }): void
  stop(args: { restart: boolean }): void
}

type AuthStruct = {
  [K in keyof MyFunctions]: {
    requiresAuth: boolean
  }
}

const auth = {
  play: {
    requiresAuth: true
  },
  pause: {
    requiresAuth: true
  },
  stop: {
    requiresAuth: false
  }
} as const satisfies AuthStruct

type Auth = typeof auth

type FunctionParameters<K extends keyof MyFunctions> = Parameters<
  MyFunctions[K]
>[0] extends undefined
  ? never
  : Parameters<MyFunctions[K]>[0]

type Data<K extends keyof MyFunctions> = (FunctionParameters<K> extends never
  ? {}
  : FunctionParameters<K>
) & (
    Auth[K] extends { requiresAuth: true }
    ? { token: string }
    : {}
  )

function runFunction<F extends keyof MyFunctions>(
  func: F,
  data: Data<F>
) {
  if(auth[func].requiresAuth) {
    data.token // Should work
  }
}

I would suppose that after running the conditional check if(auth[func].requiresAuth) the compiler would understand that data has a requiresAuth property. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Furthermore, I can't even force the compiler to accept that data has the token property by doing something like: data.token!.  How can I solve the issue?
Playground

This feels like another way of asking this question. Generic conditional types are hard for the compiler to understand, and you can't expect it to do higher order logic with them. You need to stop expecting that generic conditional types can be used for anything like this. You can either just assert like this or you can refactor all of your types to try to get something generic to work. I'd consider showing you that but I'm afraid you'll show up a few hours from now asking the same question again. How to proceed?

@jcalz I'd really appreciate you to show me how I can refactor to get generics to work. This will probably help me understand and prevent me from asking the same question. I was aware of type guards or assertion functions but I asked to know if there was a more clever solution, which I would love for you to show me.

It takes effort for me to refactor someone else's code away from complicated generic conditional types. And it seems like you still expect those to work. How much effort should I put into this if you're just going to open a similar question tomorrow? Could you explain why this one is here when it's essentially the same basic problem as the other one? As I said, I'm not averse in principle to looking at it, but I don't know if it's worth the effort if it doesn't get my point across.

@jcalz If you don't feel it's worth the effort I fully understand. But if you have some useful resources on the topic I could use to better understand how to moderate my generics usage to avoid these kinds of problems I would love to read them. Always keen to learn.

I might look at it later but right now I'm kind of burned out on this code.

I was hoping this would be amenable to the approach in ms/TS#47109 but it's not something I can figure out easily. I might look again, but I'd really suggest using a type assertion or a type guard function, or refactoring your implementation as well as your types. TS isn't a proof solver and it can't be expected to follow every logical implication for every set of variables in the program. Ah, but now I'm repeating myself from the other answer. I guess I'll have to disengage, sorry... I tried ‍♂️

I was able to get it working with this code using typeguard and some black magic (without using Any):
type HasToken = {token: string}

const isAuth = <F extends keyof MyFunctions> (func: AuthStruct[F], _: Data<F> | HasToken): _ is HasToken => {
  return func.requiresAuth;
}

function runFunction<F extends keyof MyFunctions>(
  func: F,
  data: Data<F>
) {
  if(isAuth(auth[func], data)) {
    data.token // Should work
  }
}

Probably it can be improved so that you don't need to pass the func and use a bit ugly unused variable, but hey it works.
Edit: after seeing another answer I think this might be better:
const isAuth = <F extends keyof MyFunctions> (data: Data<F> | HasToken): data is HasToken => {
  return 'token' in data;
}

// inside of function
if(auth[func].requiresAuth && isAuth(data)) {
    data.token // Should work
  }
}

or even like this, preserving maximum of your original logic
const isAuth = <F extends keyof MyFunctions> (func: AuthStruct[F], data: Data<F> | HasToken): data is HasToken => {
  return func.requiresAuth && 'token' in data;
}

// inside of function
  if(isAuth(auth[func], data)) {
    data.token // Should work
  }

